# How to set up unique constraint in database for one value in multiple columns in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, constraints, unique

I have a database with an entity company:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
private String name;
private String code;
}
```

I want to have a unique constraint for both fields but in special way. If I will add any value in e.g. name, I want to check unique through name and code columns.

Example:

```
new Company("Company 1", "123") - OK
new Company("Comp", null) - OK
new Company("CocaCola", "Comp") - not OK
new Company("Pepsi", null) - OK
```

Is it even possible?

No idea how to set it up. Normal constraints will not work in that scenario

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is not possible without querying the database for every record you want to insert. A unique constraint is limited to the column. And a composite key checks that the combination of both columns is unique

Comment: Furthermore the behavior of uniqueness on compound set of columns where NULL may appear may be database vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to have another table with a unique column with unique constraint that you will fill via a trigger on the "Company" table with not null and distinct values of the pair(name, code).